# Update ntext column

Tags: sql, sql-update, ntext

I'm having an article table which has a `ntext` column called `SearchText` which contains the whole article stripped for html.

When iterating through our +60000 articles I forgot to add a column to the SearchText content. I'm now trying to update the table using

```
update Table 
set SearchText = cast(ForgottenField as ntext) + cast(CHAR(13) as ntext) + SearchText as ntext) 
where ForgottenField <> ''
```

But I get the following error:

> Operand data type ntext is invalid for add operator.

I have read about UpdateText, but I can't figure out how to write some simple SQL to update the column

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Alter your column to be `nvarchar(max)`, `Text / nText` are deprecated. It also looks like you are storing the value from n other columns in a single string column in the same table - this is not a good idea, your `SearchText` column should be in its own FK-linked table.

Answer (score 0):

**I found this [site](https://oakdome.com/programming/SQL_Ntext_Field_Updates.php) that helped me out `(as I had to update ntext too)`**

Updating your ntext to varchar and updating like this.
update x

```
set x = convert(varchar(max),x) + ' xxx'
```